# In which location are Ubuntu packages installed?

Tags: package-management, packaging

There is an Ubuntu application called `remote desktop viewer`, I want its location to run in a script, how can I get the package details?

Answer (score 1):

`dpgk -c /var/cache/apt/archive/packagename.deb`

You can pick -c or --contents. Or if you use wajig,

`wajig contents /var/cache/apt/archive/packagename.deb` does the same.

If you just want the location of an executable file (and you know it's name) then `which progname` tells you; or you could use `$(which progname)` in your script...

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear what you want - the location of the package or the location of the installed application...

For an installed package `dpkg -L packagename` lists all the files.